# Disable UICollectionView animation on reloadData

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

For some reason, my `UICollectionView` animates the transition inside the visible cell when calling `reloadData`.

From what I understood it shouldn't do that, and that's what I am trying to do.

Why would the collection view animate on reload data? And how could I stop it?

I will be eventually using `[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES/NO]`, but I would be hoping to fix it without too much extra code.

Comment: Did you call `reloadData` inside the `updates` block of `performBatchUpdates:completion:` maybe?

Comment: Btw, if you go down the `setAnimationsEnabled` road, I'd go for:  `[UIView performWithoutAnimation:^{}]`

Comment: @plu Thanks. Nope, not using it inside `performBatch...` Also, can't use `performWithoutAnimation` as we are still targeting iOS 6.0 (`performWithoutAnimation` doesn't seem to have any effect)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 7):

```
[UIView performWithoutAnimation:^{
            [self.collectionView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0]];
        }];
```